# How to make primefaces inputTextArea fit to text?

Tags: java, css, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

i'm trying to make `<p:inputTextArea/>` looks better, now when page is loaded i can see: [image]

and when i click that `TextArea` : 
[image]

here is the code:
`<p:inputTextarea rows="6" value="#{bean.object.value}"style="width: 100%;" />`

How can i make that area would adjust its size to text ? `rows="6"` is working for a little data but it looks terrible when more chars are written

Comment: What about a JS to expand the height based on characters count?

Comment: what if cols parameter is also given in your input text area.

Comment: cols can make while space smaller but it also getting larger too much, what about that JS ? can you post some link to it ?

Comment: Did you try modifying `autoResize` attribute?

Comment: yes i tied to set `autoResize true/false` but it doesnt help

Comment: What about setting a `max-height` to it?

Comment: I couldn't find a JS for that....try what Xtreme suggested, if it also doesn't work, i do the JS and post here for you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd solve my problem with this plugin [flexibleArea.js](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/flexibleArea.js/), but if you download it it won't fix the first time you focus on the textArea, so I had to tweak it a bit.

I have added to the bind a new event which is focus.

```
$textarea.bind('keyup change cut paste focus'
```

Now to get this working, download my tweak [flexibleArea.js](http://hatemalimam.com/uploads/jquery.flexibleArea.js), include it in your xhtml, then in the document ready.

```
$(function() {         
   $('.ui-inputtextarea').flexible();    
});
```

And Here's a live [demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/textArea/main.xhtml) on Primefaces TextArea flexible, and on [github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/textArea/main.xhtml).

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Nice ! i'll keep that!

Comment: Yay, after 1 day of work finnaly it looks nice. Thanks to you again

Answer (score 3):

Self explanatory code:

```
<p:inputTextarea
    rows="#{myBean.numberOfLines(myBean.myClass.theString, 70)}"
    cols="70"
    value="#{myBean.myClass.theString}"
    autoResize="true" />

public int numberOfLines(String string, int cols) {
        int rvalue = 0;
        for (String strTmp : string.split("\n")) {
            rvalue ++;
            rvalue += strTmp.length() >= cols ? strTmp.length() / cols : 0;
        }
        return rvalue;
    }
```

Edit: This will not work for every case, because of the size of the text, but for me, it's enough.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the best way is to dynamically set the rows attribute based on the existing bean string length.  You'll need to set columns which is worth it to accomplish the goal.

```
rows="#{2 + bean.string.length()/100}" cols="100"
```

Comment: it works as you said with constant strings, but in that case when i want to edit that field it doesn't

Comment: It should autoresize during editing unless you have set it to false.

Comment: Also, your CSS style width will not work well with cols attribute, you should remove it if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. Counting cols only works if the user don't type line-breaks. After looking for a best solution I solved my case this way:

```
<p:inputTextarea
        value="#{comment.body}" 
        styleClass="no-border" readonly="true"
        style="width: 80%;height: 100%;"
        rows="#{myController.countChar(comment.body)+2}" />
```

And in MyController:

```
public int countChar(String text) {
    return StringUtils.countMatches(text, "\n");
}
```

By default, the inputTextarea has the attribute "autoResize=true".So, if you need to edit, after you  type something, the component will fit your text.